# Can't bind my controls which are in a resourcedictionary to commands

Tags: wpf, command, resourcedictionary

In my window I have a ribbon bar which has some controls. I have placed this ribbonbar in resource dictionary and used it as content of the window. I've Bound these controls to some commands like this:

```
<ribbonbar x:key="myribbonbar">
     <Buttun  Name="Btn_Undo"
              Command="{x:static Application.undo}"
              CommnadTarget="{Binding ElementName="MyControl}" />
</ribbonbar>
```

These Commands have been added to CommandBindings in the definer class of MyControl Which was used as CommnadTarget earlier. Now the Problem is the Btn_Undo is always disable and can't see the commands in MyControl's definer class. here is what I've done:
window.xaml:

```
<ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource MyRibbonbar}"/>

<Designer Name="MyControl" />
```

Designer.cs :

```
this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Undo, Undo_Executed));
```

It works in case that I put the ribbonbar in window.xaml but it makes my window too much confusing and huge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you put your ribbonbar in a User Control and use it?

Comment: I wasn't sure what difference does it make to use user control instead of resource and I didn't find anything useful after hours of searching. I could do that if it makes it work the same way. I'm actually kinda new to wpf so ... :)